# OMPython + SLURM decreasing performance by adding cores

Tags: python, performance, openmp, slurm, openmodelica

**Note** This question can be considered a followup of a [previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119762/limit-number-of-cores-used-by-ompython).

### Background

I need to run a blocks simulation. I've used OMEdit to create the system and I call omc to run the simulation using OMPython with zmq for messaging. The simulation works fine but now I need to move it to a server to simulate the system for long times.

Since the server is shared among a team of people, it uses slurm to queue the jobs. The server has 32 cores but they asked me to use only 8 while I tune my script and then 24 when I want to run my final simulation.

I've configured slurm to call my script in the following manner:

```
#!/bin/bash 
#
#SBATCH --job-name=simulation_Test_ADC2_pipe_4096s
#SBATCH --output=simulation_Test_ADC2_pipe_4096s.txt 
#
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=8
#SBATCH --time=10:00
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=10000
source activate /home/jabozzo/conda_envs/py27
#which python
OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 python ./Test_ADC2_pipe_4096s.py
```

Since I can't limit the number of cores the simulation uses with just `--cpus-per-task`, I've to also use `OMP_NUM_THREADS` (See previous question for more details). The simulations run fine and restrict themselves to the number of assigned cores.

### Problem

The simulation speed does not increase with added cores. It actually decreases, by a large factor. Here are some measurements I've made:

```
constant_time = 39s
| samples | cpus | total_time | var_time (total-constant_time) |
    10        1      1m 03s      24s
    10        4      1m 20s      41s
    10        8      1m 31s      52s
    10       16      1m 42s      63s
```

- `Samples` Is a simulation parameter and proportional to the simulation length, so all simulations are the same.
- `Cpus` is the value of `OMP_NUM_THREADS` and `--cpus-per-task`
- `total_time` is the time the python script runs.
- `var_time` is the actual simulation time, a constant of 39s is subtracted
  from `total_time` since it's related to compilation time.

I've not a clue why this is happening. Can this be disk-related?

### Update 1: Measurements

I've tested all combination of linear and non-linear solvers and none of them benefit from parallel processing. It could perfectly be that my model itself is ill-posed for parallelization. At least now I know the best solver combination for my specific simulation.

Here is the whole information in case you're curious:

```
constant_time = 39s
samples | cpu |       time        |             method           
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   10   |  8  | Integrator failed |    -ls=lis -nls=*          
   10   |  8  |  0:01:06.073854   |    -ls=klu -nls=hybrid     
   10   |  8  |  0:01:06.142541   |    -ls=klu -nls=homotopy    
   10   |  8  |  0:01:06.477493   |    -ls=klu -nls=newton     
   10   |  8  |  0:01:06.568340   |    -ls=klu -nls=kinsol     
   10   |  8  |  0:01:06.691057   |    -ls=klu -nls=mixed     
   10   |  8  |  0:01:14.684557   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=hybrid   
   10   |  8  |  0:01:14.890654   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=kinsol   
   10   |  8  |  0:01:15.113751   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=newton   
   10   |  8  |  0:01:15.152941   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=mixed   
   10   |  8  |  0:01:15.517794   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=homotopy  
   10   |  8  |  0:01:24.576667   |    -ls=lapack -nls=hybrid   
   10   |  8  |  0:01:30.822958   |    -ls=lapack -nls=mixed    
   10   |  8  |  0:01:31.096336   |    -ls=lapack -nls=newton   
   10   |  8  |  0:01:32.346660   |    -ls=lapack -nls=kinsol   
   10   |  8  |  0:01:33.206928   |    -ls=lapack -nls=homotopy  
   10   |  8  |  0:02:09.299385   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=newton 
   10   |  8  |  0:02:09.584320   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=mixed  
   10   |  8  |  0:02:10.153360   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=kinsol 
   10   |  8  |  0:02:10.221089   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=hybrid 
   10   |  8  |  0:02:10.451674   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=homotopy
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   10   |  4  | Integrator failed |    -ls=lis -nls=*          
   10   |  4  |  0:01:06.371825   |    -ls=klu -nls=homotopy    
   10   |  4  |  0:01:06.429397   |    -ls=klu -nls=mixed     
   10   |  4  |  0:01:06.583910   |    -ls=klu -nls=newton     
   10   |  4  |  0:01:06.838422   |    -ls=klu -nls=hybrid     
   10   |  4  |  0:01:06.948438   |    -ls=klu -nls=kinsol     
   10   |  4  |  0:01:13.780854   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=mixed   
   10   |  4  |  0:01:14.519788   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=kinsol   
   10   |  4  |  0:01:14.752058   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=homotopy  
   10   |  4  |  0:01:14.752473   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=newton   
   10   |  4  |  0:01:15.241889   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=hybrid   
   10   |  4  |  0:01:17.395550   |    -ls=lapack -nls=hybrid   
   10   |  4  |  0:01:23.474006   |    -ls=lapack -nls=newton   
   10   |  4  |  0:01:24.191592   |    -ls=lapack -nls=mixed    
   10   |  4  |  0:01:24.447797   |    -ls=lapack -nls=homotopy  
   10   |  4  |  0:01:24.859954   |    -ls=lapack -nls=kinsol   
   10   |  4  |  0:02:08.701093   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=homotopy
   10   |  4  |  0:02:09.668870   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=hybrid 
   10   |  4  |  0:02:09.797309   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=mixed  
   10   |  4  |  0:02:09.965805   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=kinsol 
   10   |  4  |  0:02:10.427495   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=newton 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   10   |  2  | Integrator failed |    -ls=lis -nls=*    
   10   |  2  |  0:01:05.391883   |    -ls=klu -nls=newton     
   10   |  2  |  0:01:05.503954   |    -ls=klu -nls=mixed     
   10   |  2  |  0:01:06.430987   |    -ls=klu -nls=hybrid     
   10   |  2  |  0:01:06.980129   |    -ls=klu -nls=homotopy    
   10   |  2  |  0:01:07.248639   |    -ls=klu -nls=kinsol     
   10   |  2  |  0:01:12.760185   |    -ls=lapack -nls=hybrid   
   10   |  2  |  0:01:13.615821   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=homotopy  
   10   |  2  |  0:01:13.663998   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=hybrid   
   10   |  2  |  0:01:13.787998   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=newton   
   10   |  2  |  0:01:13.950495   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=mixed   
   10   |  2  |  0:01:15.701129   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=kinsol   
   10   |  2  |  0:01:19.168938   |    -ls=lapack -nls=newton   
   10   |  2  |  0:01:19.886090   |    -ls=lapack -nls=kinsol   
   10   |  2  |  0:01:20.082878   |    -ls=lapack -nls=mixed    
   10   |  2  |  0:01:20.549771   |    -ls=lapack -nls=homotopy  
   10   |  2  |  0:02:09.020501   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=kinsol 
   10   |  2  |  0:02:09.234483   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=newton 
   10   |  2  |  0:02:09.277363   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=homotopy
   10   |  2  |  0:02:09.594828   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=hybrid 
   10   |  2  |  0:02:09.985678   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=mixed  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   10   |  1  | Integrator failed |    -ls=lis -nls=*     
   10   |  1  |  0:00:53.794419   |    -ls=lapack -nls=hybrid   
   10   |  1  |  0:00:59.929421   |    -ls=lapack -nls=kinsol   
   10   |  1  |  0:01:00.532473   |    -ls=lapack -nls=newton   
   10   |  1  |  0:01:00.810815   |    -ls=lapack -nls=mixed    
   10   |  1  |  0:01:01.446853   |    -ls=lapack -nls=homotopy  
   10   |  1  |  0:01:07.081730   |    -ls=klu -nls=homotopy    
   10   |  1  |  0:01:07.193936   |    -ls=klu -nls=mixed     
   10   |  1  |  0:01:07.642832   |    -ls=klu -nls=hybrid     
   10   |  1  |  0:01:08.086962   |    -ls=klu -nls=kinsol     
   10   |  1  |  0:01:08.125929   |    -ls=klu -nls=newton     
   10   |  1  |  0:01:15.551880   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=newton   
   10   |  1  |  0:01:15.657809   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=mixed   
   10   |  1  |  0:01:15.683899   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=hybrid   
   10   |  1  |  0:01:15.767198   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=homotopy  
   10   |  1  |  0:01:15.956935   |    -ls=umfpack -nls=kinsol   
   10   |  1  |  0:02:10.154189   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=newton 
   10   |  1  |  0:02:10.206857   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=kinsol 
   10   |  1  |  0:02:10.803616   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=homotopy
   10   |  1  |  0:02:10.848160   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=mixed  
   10   |  1  |  0:02:11.545972   |    -ls=totalpivot -nls=hybrid
```

Comment: What kind of flags do you set when calling the simulation? Any of the experimental code generators such as --hpcomCode? Modelica models usually do not benefit from parallel code since the cost of synchronisation is very large relative to the work. Imagine solving a 3x3 linear system; no need to start a thread to solve that in parallel.

Comment: I'm using `--hpcomCode=openmp` and for simulation `-mei`. I've diasabled the first flag but I got the same performance results. My system size is 8828 equations, of which 6445 are trivial, and 8828 variables. I don't have a sense if that is a big or a small system.

Comment: If you stopped using `--hpcomCode=openmp` but performance is still affected by `OMP_NUM_THREADS` I would suspect that it is one of the numerical solvers that affects performance; possibly lapack? Hard to guess without seeing the actual model or being able to reproduce it myself. I would suspect that `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` is reasonable for most Modelica models since most of the problems are rather serial in nature (a size of <2000 non-trivial variables is generally considered small; if it was 2000 state variables it could be considered larger; for large systems you probably want sparse solvers).